# CSS to AI/vector

Tags: javascript, css, image, svg, pdf-generation

I am building a flyer generator using css/js. I'd like to output the final product to a layered ai/vector.  There is SVG but I am not familiar with it enough to tell if it can be of use.  Anyone have suggestions on what I could explore to achieve this?  The server will be Node and I expect server side processing of course.  So far going to PDF is an option but have not yet found how to tell the layers on it (I admit I haven't looked at it in depth - just trying to get the general view right now)

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting vector output, then SVG is definitely a good choice. However, it seems you want to first use HTML and then convert that to some vector format. Generating and manipulating SVG directly in the browser using JavaScript might be a better choice that avoids trouble during a conversion, however that conversion might look like. You can either use the standard DOM methods for manipulating the SVG, or you can use a library like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). There are some caveats, though:

- You have to take care of text line breaks yourself as SVG 1.2's `<textArea>` element is not yet widely supported.
- Making text justify left and right has to be taken care of using the [`word-spacing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#WordSpacingProperty) that needs to be adjusted whenever the text was manipulated. You'd have to check the text length using the `getBBox()` method and re-calculate the word spacing each time.
- SVG does not have a dynamic reflow. Positions don't change depending on width/height of other elements. For generating things like flyers, this might be considered the better choice because some minor change won't destroy the whole "page" layout.
- Making SVG text editable à la `contenteditable="true"` is not supported by SVG.

A possible workaround for the mentioned limitations considering `<textArea>`, justified text and editable text would be to use HTML inside SVG as [`<foreignObject>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects) and only convert those to real SVG as a final step.

In SVG, layers are achieved using `<g>` ("group") elements.